# How to convert array of Byte to PByte in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointers, delphi-5

I'm using Delphi 5. I define an array of byte, as follows:

```
Buffer: Array of BYTE;
```

How to convert it to a PByte pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dynamic array is implemented as a pointer, so you can simply type-cast it as-is:

```pascal
var
  Buffer: array of Byte;
  P: PByte;
begin
  SetLength(Buffer, ...);
  P := PByte(Buffer);
  ...
end;
```

If you don't want to rely on this implementation detail, you can instead take the memory address of the 1st byte in the array:

```pascal
P := @Buffer[0];
```

Comment: But beware of the possible range-check exception if `Buffer[0]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. I modify my question to describe the case in more details. If I use PByte(Buffer) in MyFun, I will get compiler error "Invalid cast". With PByte(@Buffer[0]) is OK. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Two ways to do this:

```
var
  P: PByte;
....
P := @Buffer[0]; // no cast, compiler can check type safety
P := PByte(Buffer); // implementation detail, dynamic array variable is pointer to first element
```

Note that the former leads to a range error if range checking is enabled and the array is empty. Because of this I tend to prefer the latter, although you may criticise the direct pointer cast for lacking type safety.

Comment: Thanks. But I have two questions: 1) I remember the first byte in the array is the count of the items, so if I use PByte(Buffer), will the pointer actually point to the counter, instead of the first element? 2) I try to use Inspect in Delphi to see (@Buffer[0]) and get a correct address, however, when I use PByte(Buffer), I get "Expression Error", why?

Comment: First byte is not the counter. You are thinking of a shortstring. No compiler error here with the cast. The debugger may not be able to evaluate it but there's not much you can do about that short of upgrading.

Comment: Thank you. I modify my question to describe the case in more details. If I use PByte(Buffer) in MyFun, I will get compiler error "Invalid cast". With PByte(@Buffer[0]) is OK.

Comment: I rolled back the question. You asked originally about a *dynamic array*. However, your edit talks about an *open array*. These are very different things, and so I rolled back the edit because it's too late to change the question after you have two answers. However, for an open array you have to use `@Buffer[0]`.

Comment: OK. I see. Thank you very much. Originally I think they are the same thing so I just write a short version of my question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, it's a common source of confusion. The syntax is identical, but the meaning is very different depending on the context.